# Formatting of Tabular environment

Tags: tables

I have the following latex code for a table, but would like to alter the output to match the image below it. Could anyone tell me how I could do this?

```
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
\hline
& Week 1 & week 2 & Week 3 \\\hline\hline
$\ell$ & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
$h$ & 2 & 2 & 2 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that short lines from a first-line rectangle are undesired, we can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
%\hline
\cline{2-4}
%& Week 1 & week 2 & Week 3 \\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& Week 1 & week 2 & Week 3 \\
\cline{2-4}\noalign{\vskip2pt}\cline{1-4}
$\ell$ & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
$h$ & 2 & 2 & 2 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\vskip\doublerulesep` instead of a hardcoded `2pt`. Also `\hline` works in place of `\cline{1-4}`

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,hhline}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
\hhline{~---}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& Week 1 & week 2 & Week 3 \\
\hhline{-===}
$\ell$ & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
$h$ & 2 & 2 & 2 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option, using [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs)

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
           & Week 1 & Week 2 & Week 3 \\
    \midrule
    $\ell$ & 1      & 1      & 1      \\
    $h$    & 2      & 2      & 2      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the commands `\cmidrule{a-b}`to take care of the special case where the lines don't go into the first of the cells. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables is a great place to start for advance tables.

Comment: `\cmidrule` comes from `booktabs`, and wouldn't work to get exactly that output. Try `\cline{2-4}` instead.